# Проблема с DrawerLayout

Tags: android, ui, android-xml, drawerlayout

Вот с этим

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:title="26.06.2018"
        />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_main_drawer"/>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

получается это [image]

---

Насколько я понял, это происходит из-за `android:layout_height="match_parent"`
 в корневом `LinearLayout` и `DrawerLayout`. У `DrawerLayout` обязательно должно быть `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

**Как мне обыграть данную ситуацию?**

Comment: У вас просто кривая разметка. Как вы хотите обыграть ситуацию не совсем понятно. Можно сделать fitsystemwindows а можно его убрать   android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

Comment: Сделал android:fitsSystemWindows="false", все норм